# Download file from list and assigning different names

Tags: wget

I have a long list of files to download with the following syntax:

```
https://url.url/YYYY/MM/DD/file.pdf
```

Of course YYYY is the year, MM the month, DD the day.

Is there a way to download the files on this list and assign each of them a name in the form YYYY-MM-DD.pdf? Or to keep the directories and have each file.pdf in its proper directory?

Comment: Where are you getting this list from? Is it in a file? have you tried anything?

Comment: The list was in a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially have two options here, and depending on how and where you're getting the list of files from, one may be better than the other:

1. You have a list of all URLs: In this case, your only choice is to write a script that reads each line, parses the URL and invokes Wget with the right output filename. This is extremely easy to do (~5 lines of bash)
2. The website has a listing / index.html page that links to all the files you want. This allows you to call `wget` recursively with the `-r` option. In this case, the entire file hierarchy will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks! I've followed your first suggestion and [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196253/how-do-you-rename-files-specifically-in-a-list-that-wget-will-use/196267#comment329176_196267) has been very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename the files while downloading them. `wget` will preserve the directory structure, and you may rename the files to your desired naming convention later. Read `man wget` (or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/wget.1.html )

Comment: What about ` -O file` / ` --output-document=file` ? Like `wget -O YYYY-MM-DD.pdf https://url.url/YYYY/MM/DD/file.pdf`